# \parbox not working, or invisible?

Tags: preamble, parbox

[image]I want to use \parbox to, well, make a box around text.  But when I typeset, I just get the text and no box... I have no idea why.  I am afraid it could be something in my preamble... I keep including packages as I work through a long series of documents and I don't know how they might interact.  Including TeX code and an image of what I get when I typeset.  Any help much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize, geometry, booktabs, hyperref, polynom, enumerate, amssymb,amsmath, graphicx,fancyhdr,empheq}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\usepackage[super]{nth}
\setlength\parindent{0.0in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{Day 16[![enter image description here][1]][1]}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
}


\begin{document}
\title {\textbf{Title}\\[0.2em]\smaller{}\textbf{Blah}: Blah}

\author{\copyright{} Name}
\date{April 2023}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\parbox{\textwidth} { Why won't my box show up? }\\~\\


\end{document}
```

Comment: a parbox makes a tex box, a non-breakable unit,it does not draw any rules,use `\fbox{\parbox{..}{...}}` to have a frame round the box

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

a parbox makes a tex box, a non-breakable unit,it does not draw any rules,use `\fbox{\parbox{..}{...}}` to have a frame round the box